# Europe - where to buy domain name?

Tags: hosting, domain-name

I have read, that for a website with global ambitious is better to buy hosting at US provider than the local one (I am from Central Europe) - mainly because of shorter loading time of a website.

I think it can be kind of truth.

But applies it also for domain names? Or for domain name it doesn't matter?

Comment: Just don't use GoDaddy.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly we don't really do shopping questions on here but I'll try to answer anyway.

I think it's increasingly less important where a web-site actually resides so long as you're using a geographically dispersed CDN to handle your static content. Certainly if you're actual code tends to be quite dense then you may wish to site your servers globally too to minimise latency but usually you can fix that via code changes.

As for where to get domain names? well so long as you stick to one of the big registrars (which do tend to be in the West) then it's kind of irrelevant - don't forget that pretty much any registrar can sell you any TLD domain so there's some real benefits of buying all your domains from one company - means only one renewal and you can see all your domains in one management site.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Chopper3 . In case your choice should be wide geographical, you do not have to pay many attention to hosting provider but rather for someone with more PoPs that could deliver your content fast to customer from origin hosting point (check wiki for Content delivery network)